# Angular Material вкладки справа, вертикальный текст

Tags: angular

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-нибудь знает, как можно сделать то же самое, только средствами (рекомендованного Ангуляром) движка Ангуляр Материал?
Гуглил, но полной информации не нашёл.
Версия Ангуляра 6 или 7.

Comment: ну там есть компоненты `mat-tab-group + mat-tab`, почитайте документацию, а потом просто напишите стили типа `transform: rotate(90deg)`

Comment: Читал. Там всё странно, методами костылей и велосипедов. Если кто-нибудь реализовал нормально - пожалуйста, поделитесь

Comment: извините, я не понимаю что для вас костыль и велосипед

Comment: Пока не привык к Ангуляру Материал, но уже понимаю, что там какой-то свой синтаксис и стиль написания. В примерах, которые не решали мою проблему, а делали что-то отдалённо похожее, разные части были завёрнуты в разные div с кучей строк стиля. Я так понимаю, что стиль Ангуляра Материал - настраивать компонент. Вот примера именно настройки я найти и не могу.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

Comment: Читал. Там только горизонтальные. Функционала, как на картинке, нет

Comment: так переверните через стили ;)